# Name not recognized error in List.Generate

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a table with 10 columns, StepDet 1 - StepDet 10. In each one is an embedded table. I want to expand each table but not with all the columns. I only want to expand Step Name and Step 1 - 10.

I tried the below code, but I get an error that Expression.Error: The name 'prevTable' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

I would appreciate any help to move forward.

```
let
    // Load the query
    Source = Source_name,

    // Generate the list of columns to expand
    columnsToExpand = List.Generate(
        () => [i = 1],
        each [i] <= 10,
        each [i = [i] + 1],
        each "StepDet " & Text.From([i])
    ),

    // Expand the columns
    expandedTable = List.Last(List.Generate(
        () => [i = 0, prevTable = Source],
        each [i] <= List.Count(columnsToExpand)-1,
        each [
            i = [i] + 1,
            prevTable = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
                prevTable,
                columnsToExpand{[i]},
                {"Step Name", "ActionDet 1", "ActionDet 2", "ActionDet 3", "ActionDet 4", "ActionDet 5", "ActionDet 6", "ActionDet 7", "ActionDet 8", "ActionDet 9", "ActionDet 10"},
                List.Transform(
                    {"Step Name", "ActionDet 1", "ActionDet 2", "ActionDet 3", "ActionDet 4", "ActionDet 5", "ActionDet 6", "ActionDet 7", "ActionDet 8", "ActionDet 9", "ActionDet 10"},
                    each columnsToExpand{[i]} & "." & _
                )
            )
        ],
        each [prevTable]
    ))
in
    expandedTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this get you closer?

```
let Source = <  >,
columnsToExpand = List.Transform({1 .. 10}, each "StepDet "&Text.From(_)) & {"Step Name"},
#"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source,  List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),columnsToExpand), "Attribute", "Value"),
ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Unpivoted Columns", "Value"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
#"Expanded" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Unpivoted Columns", "Value",ColumnsToExpand ,ColumnsToExpand )
in  #"Expanded"
```

Comment: Not really. Maybe I should have mentioned that All the tables to be expanded have only 1 row. So unpivoting in this sense does not make much sense?

Comment: Makes sense to me. I wouldn't want to expand 10 columns sideways and then wind up with 10 x Z columns. Is that the desired outcome? You didn't post an image or sample data to show what your desired end state is, so it's sort of hard to guess

Comment: Thank you, I solved the issue. As you said getting 10 x columns is the desired outcome in this case.